# Keyboard shortcut in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard

Is there any shortcut in excel that will enlarge the entire column width & row height by using keyboard?

Comment: Have you used Macro Recorder before ?

Comment: No i have not used macro before

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want to achieve. Just one column and all rows? All rows and all columns? Do you want each cell to expand to show the complete contents? Do you have wrap text enabled? Do you have merged cells? With merged cells, no macro or keyboard shortcut will help. You will need to adjust the cell height manually. You may want to post a link to a sample file. If you cannot yet post a link since you are a new user, just post the URL. People here will know how to make that into a link.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2010, you can do this using keyboard navigation of the ribbon. <kbd>Alt-H-O</kbd> gets you to the **Format** menu, from which you can press <kbd>H</kbd> for **Row Height** or <kbd>W</kbd> for **Column Width**. Alternatively, by right-clicking the menu (or any item on it), you can add it to the Quick Access Toolbar at the top of the window, which means you can get to it using <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>1-9</kbd> (the number row on your keyboard).

(This isn't special knowledge - just press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to flash up keyboard shortcuts on each menu item.)

You could use a macro. But I'd tend to discourage this since it breaks Undo functionality.

Answer (score 1):

pres <kbd>alt</kbd> then press `h` then press `o` and then press `i`, Excel will expand the width of that column to fit the content in the cell you selected, so you can first use `ctrl + shift + up`or `down`or `left` or `right`arrow key to select content,then you then `alt`,`h`,`o`,`i` key sequences.